# SSRS passing parameter to SSAS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameter-passing, ssas, analysis

I have an SSRS report that passes a datetime parameter with a datepicker to my analysis service.
The value field in my cube is datetime.

I get the error:

> the strtoset function expects a tuple set expression for the 1 argument. a string or numeric expression was used.

This is the syntax passed to my SSAS server:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Transactions Count] } ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@PaymulDateAlternateTimeKey) ) ON COLUMNS FROM [Transactions]) WHERE ( IIF( STRTOSET(@PaymulDateAlternateTimeKey).Count = 1, STRTOSET(@PaymulDateAlternateTimeKey), [Paymul Date].[AlternateTimeKey].currentmember ) ) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. STRTOSET is okay, if you create the full path (SSAS) in your required format. In my case I had to edit the FX in the parameter section of the dataset (SSRS - Report Builder) to:

```
="[Paymul Date].[AlternateTimeKey].&["+format(Parameters!PaymulDateAlternateTimeKey.Value,"yyyy-MM-dd")+"T00:00:00]"
```

From there on you can edit as if you wish. DateAdd, CDate, Now() or Today().
Just be aware that you have to build the whole string with the full path.

Answer (score -1):

According to the error message this part went wrong :
STRTOSET(@PaymulDateAlternateTimeKey)

StrToSet expect a string expression that can specify a set. So a datatime type is not qualified.

Are you trying to pass multivalued parameter? If so, you'd need to  follow the method, mentioned like in [Passing Multiple Member Key values in Parameter](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9b077e66-7a88-4d12-97d6-29f5bbde784d/passing-multiple-member-key-values-in-parameter?forum=sqlanalysisservices)

Comment: I'm passing only one date parameter to my cube.